# Random Spawning Traffic at Pace Fitting "Frogger"-style Gameplay

Tags: unity, c#, random, spawning

In my game level, you have to cross a busy road to buy something and then cross back again. The general gameplay mechanics are now set up and playable. But I wanted to know if this routine I used to randomly spawn the cars can be improved upon.

[image: screenshot]

So far, I simply set the percentage chance of it spawning a car that frame (I have 0.01f for now), and only call the spawnCar() method when my random number 0-1 is less than that chance. Like so:

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Random.Range(0f, 1f) < 0.01f)
            SpawnCar();
        
    }

    void SpawnCar()
    {
        Color color = new Color(Random.Range(0,2), Random.Range(0, 2), Random.Range(0, 2), 1);
        if (Random.Range(0, 2) == 0)
        {

            Car car = Instantiate(carPrefab, new Vector3(SPAWN_POSITION_X, 0, Random.Range(1, LANE_WIDTH)), Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0));
            car.InitCar(true, Random.Range(8,15), color);

        }
        else
        {
            Car car = Instantiate(carPrefab, new Vector3(-SPAWN_POSITION_X, 0, -Random.Range(1, LANE_WIDTH)), Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0));
            car.InitCar(false, Random.Range(8, 15), color);
        }
    }
```

But sometimes there are lots of cars, sometimes not so many. I am wondering if there are better ways, or other factors I can account for when spawning the cars to give a better difficulty curve. (The level is constantly revisited so ideally it will get harder and harder perhaps 10 or so times until it's at 'max difficulty')

Comment: I see a method body right above the `SpawnCar()` method. How often is this called? What's the method signature, and where's it called from? I think that's the starting point to resolving your issue.

Comment: sorry i must have mis-pasted. That is the Update() loop. How can I improve on this though? I'm not great at maths but feel there is a similar but better solution I am missing

Comment: You may also be interested in [How to make obstacles spawn randomly but still leave a way for player to pass?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/171387/39518)

Comment: This was exactly the kind of thing i was imagining but could not put into words or coherent thoughts. So far I particularly like the 'deal from deck and have 'gap' cards' idea. I am going to explore that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I see a big problem with your code. You are potentially spawining a car each `Update`. That means you are making the spawn frequency dependent on the update frequency, which is tied to the framerate. That means players with more powerful hardware who have a higher framerate will encounter more cars than players with lower framerate.

There are several ways you can fix that problem. You could move your spawning code from `Update` to `FixedUpdate`. Or you could put the spawning code into a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which uses `yield return WaitForSeconds(seconds);` in order to roll for spawns in regular intervals.

But the solution I would prefer could also be used to solve the problem you actually posted about, namely to prevent clustering and dry-spells: Implement your own timing logic in Update using the [`Time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time.html) class.

- Have a variable which tracks the time until you spawn the next car
- Have your update-method reduce that variable by `Time.deltatTime` (seconds since the last update).
- When it's below 0, spawn a new car.
- After you spawned a car, roll a random number between two values to determine the time until the next car is going to spawn.

This way you can control precisely how much minimum and maximum time you have between two spawns. The script could look something like that:

```
public float minTimeToNextCar = 1.0f; // change to taste
public float maxTimeToNextCar = 2.0f; // change to taste
private float timeToNextCar;

void Start() {
    // initialize timeToNextCar with a random value so not all cars spawn at once on start
    timeToNextCar = Random.Range(minTimeToNextCar, maxTimeToNextCar);
}

void Update() {
    // reduce the time left until the next car spawn
    timeToNextCar -= Time.deltaTime;
    // check if it is time to instantiate a new car
    if (timeToNextCar <= 0.0f) {
        /* Your code to instantiate a car */
        // roll time until next car spawn
        timeToNextCar += Random.Range(minTimeToNextCar, maxTimeToNextCar);
    }
}
```

You might notice that the two variables which control the spawn frequency are public. That gives you several options to control them externally. You could either create your own difficulty controller script which sets the min and max time of several spawns based on the the elapsed time. Or use a solution I find very elegant: Control those values via curves in a [Timeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/TimelineSection.html).

Comment: simple and awesome! thank you. I'm glad I asked as I may have arrived at something similar to this eventually, but would have taken me hours and I still would have wondered if this was a decent way to do it or not. I can implement this immediately. Nice one! (Also thanks for pointing out about the CPU speed problem I'd created)

Comment: Timeline Asset is new to me. Will defo check it out, sure to be lots of uses for that